# How to force a started program's tray icon to appear from a scheduled task set to run whether the user is logged on or not?

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, jscript

On Windows, a scheduled task set to run whether the user is logged on or not and whose batch file is launching another program will prevent that newly launched program to display its tray icon.

On the other hand, the same scheduled task set to only run if the user is logged on will spawn the program's tray icon, but will have the undesired effect of also spawning a command prompt window for a split second AND it's not the desired situation, because this scheduled task has to run even before any user logged on that computer anyway.

So, is there a way to force a launched program's tray icon to display when called from a scheduled task set to run whether the user is logged on or not? (even if this means that a specific Windows profile user/pass had to be specified in the batch file)

Here's the batch file executed from the scheduled task, note the tray icon missing is on shell.Run line at the bottom:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal

set "URL=http://**********HIDDEN**********.php?pull=1";
cscript /nologo /e:jscript "%~f0" "%URL%";

goto :EOF
@end

var x = WSH.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

x.open("GET",WSH.Arguments(0),false,"********","********");
x.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
x.send('');
while (x.readyState != 4) WSH.Sleep(50);

if (x.status == 200 && x.responseText == '1') {
    var shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
    shell.Run('"C:\\Program Files\\TightVNC\\tvnserver.exe"');
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for, _if nobody is logged on there's no desktop or taskbar to view so how does anybody know, or why would they care, if the tray icon is there or not?_ The same goes for the command prompt flashing, however this may be fixable, were you to provide the batch file and make this an on-topic question.

Comment: I was thinking on renaming the question title as: "How to force a program's tray icon to appear when started from scheduled task set to run whether the user is logged on or not" but it was a bit too long to fit.  Why do they care? It's mostly because the program that is started by that scheduled task's batch file can cause issues when started in multiple instances, so to help reduce the chances this happens, if the tray icon is showing like normal, then the user would know there's no need to launch another instance or they could quit that program, which they can't when the tray icon is absent.

Comment: If the user has not logged on there is no tray icon because the desktop and taskbar are not loaded yet, so a tray icon is only necessary for logged on users, isn't it? Regardless of that issue, this site provides help with fully explained specific issues with your [mcve] code. You need to provide it if you want us to help you with it; you can do that by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50807571/edit), _remembering to format the code using the `{}` button_.

Comment: I was doing it while you were reading my previous comment.  Refresh the page :)

Comment: Wouldn't you expect that a tray icon in a users taskbar system tray is user specific/controllable. If you are running it as a scheduled task as that user it may follow that they would get the tray icon. Perhaps you should explain the parameters under which the scheduled task is set to run.

Comment: This is a pull batch file, it checks on a remote server for a byte, if that byte is 1 then TightVNC launches on the local computer.  That program will not work correctly if run twice concurrently, that's why the tray icon needs to be visible in order to prevent the user from launching another instance.  What I'm looking for is a way to force the tray icon to show when a user is logged in.  Maybe in the batch file it could refresh the tray icons? Because it's worth mentioning the program runs as the correct user in task manager (like it would if manually launched) it's just the icon not showing

Comment: Just to clarify: I am running the scheduled task as that user and no, the icon is not showing, it's only showing when the scheduled task is set to run only if the user is logged in (altough in every test I did, the user was logged in (me))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I ended up making a second scheduled task which only runs when the user is logged in and that batch file starts the program, making its tray icon visible.  It runs 3 seconds after the first scheduled task which, as seen in the OP, pulls a byte from the server but then at the bottom, instead of doing a shell.Run(), it creates a cookie text file and the second scheduled task picks it up 3 seconds later.

So when the computer is unattended/logged out of any Windows session, the first scheduled task runs a service instead of an app (no icon but who cares) but then when an user logs in a Windows session, the second scheduled task picks up the cookie text file left by the first scheduled task and pops the tray icon up.

Works like a charm, but **it's worth noting that anything launched from a scheduled task  set to run on whether an user is logged in or not will NEVER display any taskbar/tray/notification icon, EVER.**  All subsequent programs, processes or commands bubbling from that scheduled task will be invisible to the user, like if ran under a private session, even tough the Windows account user/pass is specified in the scheduled task and that the program runs as that specified user account.  It's just the way scheduled tasks are, it's kind of a limitation, IMO, but it can be overcome with the hack mentioned above.

To prevent any kind of disruption since this scheduled task runs every 5 minutes, I used the 8KB "CMDH.exe" binary which I bundled with the batch files I deployed on the computers.  http://www.gate2.net/tools/cmdh/cmdh.html

Comment: I have the same problem as you had- simply want to start an app (with INTERFACE) after reboot the server (2019) and SHOW it in the task bar. UNBELIEAVABLE that this should not be possible with Server 2019 and there is no easy workaround - this way, I can't use it :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have solved in this way on windows 10 pro, I created schedules that are executed at the start of the system regardless of the connected user, in this way they are executed and remain not visible. Then I created Of same schedules that are executed when logged in to any user, in this way the icon is shown, a new instance is not created because it is not consetita in the schedule, even Checking in the taskmanager